# Dead letter queue Qpid

Tags: junit, rabbitmq, spring-integration, qpid

i m using rabbit template with qpid broker in test environment .everything works fine except dead letter queues are not functioning. They get the message but they never pass the message. all the queues are defined in rabbit-context file

Comment: Would be great to have some simple project on GitHub to let us to play with that locally. Thanks

Comment: And also, please, provide there a README how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this issue. I believe it is a consequence of the suffixes used for dead-letter queues and exchanges. Rabbit uses ".dlq", whereas by default qpid uses "_DLQ". It may be possible to override this in qpid using the `qpid.broker_dead_letter_queue_suffix` system property.